# How do I display the value of a heatmap element by hovering the cursor over it?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, mplcursors

I would like to display the value of a particular element of a heatmap when I hover the mouse over it.

I have got it to display the value of the heatmap but it displayed information I do not want as well and when I first run the program, there are a lot of errors and I cannot figure out why.

I have tried various methods of displaying the value that I have seen online, such as `datacursor(hover=True)` but `mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)` is the only one that 'works'.

```
import tkinter as tk                                                    
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import numpy as np
from math import pi
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpldatacursor import datacursor
import mplcursors

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()                                                          
root.title("Stage 2 GUI")                                               
root.geometry("1270x590")  

mapArr = np.zeros([2,2],dtype=float)

mapArr=([113,62,31,63],
        [50,101,72,47],
        [92,10,40,12],
        [83,21,128,16])

xy=(['A','B','C','D','E','F'])


figure, axis = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,7))                              
heatmap = axis.imshow(
    mapArr,cmap="gray",interpolation='nearest',vmin=0, vmax=128)        

heatmap.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)                             
heatmap.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

cb = figure.colorbar(heatmap)                                           

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, root)                                
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=-60,y=-60)                               

mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)

plt.show()
```

I would like to display the value of the heatmap element but not the x and y coordinates but I am not sure how to remove/ customise the information displayed and I would like it if there were not errors whenever I run the program (even if it technically does work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to decide if you want to use pyplot or embedd matplotlib into tk. The following assumes you want to embedd (in that case, don't use pyplot!!).

#### Using mplcursors

The [mplcursors documentation](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#customization) explains how to customize the output. Essentially it consists of connecting to an event called `"add"`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk
import mplcursors

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1270x590")  

mapArr=np.array(([113,62,31,63],
                 [50,101,72,47],
                 [92,10,40,12],
                 [83,21,128,16]))

xy=(['A','B','C','D','E','F'])


fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot()

heatmap = ax.imshow(mapArr,cmap="gray",interpolation='nearest',vmin=0, vmax=128)        

cb = fig.colorbar(heatmap)                                           

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)                                
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=60,y=60)                               

cursor = mplcursors.cursor(heatmap, hover=True)

@cursor.connect("add")
def on_add(sel):
    i,j = sel.target.index
    sel.annotation.set_text(mapArr[i,j])

tk.mainloop()
```

### Manually crating the hover box

You can do the same as above without the use of mplcursors. This would be done by creating an annotation and changing its position and text depending on the mouse position.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1270x590")  

mapArr=np.array(([113,62,31,63],
                 [50,101,72,47],
                 [92,10,40,12],
                 [83,21,128,16]))

xy=(['A','B','C','D','E','F'])


fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot()

heatmap = ax.imshow(mapArr,cmap="gray",interpolation='nearest',vmin=0, vmax=128)        

cb = fig.colorbar(heatmap)                                           

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)                                
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=60,y=60)                               

annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0,0), xytext=(20,20), textcoords="offset points",
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"), visible=False,
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"))

def hover(event):
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        x,y = event.xdata, event.ydata
        j,i = np.round(np.array((x,y))).astype(int)
        annot.xy = (x,y)
        annot.set_text(str(mapArr[i,j]))
        annot.set_visible(True)
    else:
        annot.set_visible(False)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there a way of disabling the hoverbox once created? For example if a `tk.Checkbutton` is used? I tried adding `if checkbuttonvariable==0:` into the line `if event.inaxex==ax:` by anding them but this did not work. I then tried setting `annot.set_visable(False)` but this also did not work. Can it be done?

Comment: @MRB in `hover` use `print(checkbuttonvariable)` and `print(type(checkbuttonvariable))` to see what you get. Maybe you get string `"0"`, not integer `0`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I noticed when trying the code you suggested the heatmap values are inverted and not match up with the original array? It is as if they have been flipped from top right to bottom left?

Comment: @MBR change `[j,i]` to `[i,j]` and you get correct values.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to `coursor` function which will change text in annotation

```
cursor = mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)

@cursor.connect("add")
def on_mouse_move(sel):
    x = sel.target[0]
    y = sel.target[1]

    value = sel.artist.get_cursor_data(_Event(x, y))

    sel.annotation.set_text("value {} at ({:1.2f}, {:1.2f})".format(value, x,y))
```

To get value it needs `namedtuple` (I found it in Cursor's source code)

```
from collections import namedtuple

_Event = namedtuple('_Event', 'xdata ydata')
```

Full working example (only needed code so there is no errors)

```
import tkinter as tk                                                    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

# --- data ---

mapArr = (
    [113, 62, 31, 63],
    [50, 101, 72, 47],
    [92, 10, 40, 12],
    [83, 21, 128, 16]
)

xy = ('A','B','C','D','E','F')

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()                                                          

figure, axis = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 7))

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, root)                                
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)

heatmap = axis.imshow(mapArr, cmap="gray", interpolation='nearest', vmin=0, vmax=128)        
heatmap.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)                             
heatmap.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

colorbar = figure.colorbar(heatmap)                                           

#--- connect function to cursor

from collections import namedtuple
_Event = namedtuple('_Event', 'xdata ydata')

cursor = mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)

@cursor.connect("add")
def on_mouse_move(sel):
    x = sel.target[0]
    y = sel.target[1]

    value = sel.artist.get_cursor_data(_Event(x, y))

    sel.annotation.set_text("value {} at ({:1.2f}, {:1.2f})".format(value, x,y))

#--- 

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** Using @ImportanceOfBeingErnest example I found where was my mistake in version with `canvas.mpl_connect()` and now it works.

This example shows how to use `Checkbutton` to turn on/off annotation.

```
import tkinter as tk                                                    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

# --- data ---

mapArr = (
    [113, 62, 31, 63],
    [50, 101, 72, 47],
    [92, 10, 40, 12],
    [83, 21, 128, 16]
)

xy = ('A','B','C','D','E','F')

# --- functions ---

def on_mouse_move(event):
    if checkbuttonvariable.get() == 0:
        return

    if event.inaxes == axis:
        annotation.xy = (event.xdata, event.ydata)
        row = int(round(event.ydata))
        col = int(round(event.xdata))
        value = mapArr[row][col]
        annotation.set_text(str(value))
        annotation.set_visible(True)
    else:
        annotation.set_visible(False)
    canvas.draw()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()                                                          

figure, axis = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 7))

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, root)                                
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)

heatmap = axis.imshow(mapArr, cmap="gray", interpolation='nearest', vmin=0, vmax=128)        
heatmap.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)                             
heatmap.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

colorbar = figure.colorbar(heatmap)

# ---

annotation = axis.annotate("", xy=(0,0), xytext=(20,20), textcoords="offset points",
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"), visible=False,
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"))

canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_mouse_move)

# ---

checkbuttonvariable = tk.IntVar(value=1)
button = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='visible', variable=checkbuttonvariable)
button.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I added example with `Checkbutton`